# Time stamp when worksheet was last modified

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with several worksheets and I need to separately time-stamp when each sheet was last modified. I found the code below but it gives me when the whole workbook was last modified, as opposed to each individual sheet. I have tried a few variations but couldn't get it to work. Any suggestions on how to do it?

```
Public Function LastUpdated()
    LastUpdated= Format(FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.FullName), "m/d/yy h:n ampm")
End Function
```

Comment: Use a `Workbook_SheetChange` event. Where is the timestamp supposed to go?

Comment: @Rory in any cell within the worksheet; wanted a function so I could do =LastUpdated()

Comment: A `Change` event will be far easier to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **each** worksheet enter the following event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count).Value = Now
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It records the date/time that a cell is changed in the bottom right of the worksheet.  Then in a Standard Module enter the following *UDF()*:

```
Public Function Updatee() As Date
    Application.Volatile

    Dim w As Worksheet
    Set w = Application.Caller.Parent

    Updatee = w.Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count).Value
End Function
```

It will display the contents of that bottom-right cell for that worksheet.

Comment: precisely what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Putting the following in the ThisWorkbook object would write the stamp to cell C3 (3rd row, 3rd column)

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Parent.Cells(3, 3) = Format(Now, "m/d/yy h:n ampm")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```